# Put instead of post in Spring-Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, http

What happens if I use put instead of post to create new resources?
I want to register new user, but what happens if I use put method

Answer (score 0):

perhaps I got an answer. It will still create resources but it won't follow W3Standards.
refer to the link 
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/rest/put-versus-post
and 
https://restfulapi.net/rest-put-vs-post/

Answer (score 0):

Nothing changes. @PutMapping is just to mark the request as Update operation.

refer : [www.javaguides.net](https://www.javaguides.net/2018/11/spring-getmapping-postmapping-putmapping-deletemapping-patchmapping.html)